# Architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting this error 'The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application' while trying to generate a scaffold to test database connectivity.

I know ,if I'm using a 64-bit windows version the default is to use the 64-bit ODBC version.

I am now trying to run the application with Windows 7 64 bit.  I have configured the 32-bit ODBC Access drivers instead of the 64 bit drivers by running the ODBC driver setup page at:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

How can I access 64-bit ODBC version. It is not available in my system. Can I have download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't much experience with this however the data sources in "Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources"
are different than C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe and may me the 64bit version you're looking for.